# How to programmatically set existing image in media library the featured image for a post in wordpress

Tags: php, post-thumbnails

I have uploaded some images to the wordpress media library. Now I am going to create some posts using php and want to use those already uploaded images as featured image for these posts respectively. How to set image as featured image for a post.
I have tried below code. but it sets an empty image as featured image to posts.

```
function set_featured_image($post_id, $image_url){
global $wpdb;
$attachment = $wpdb->get_col($wpdb->prepare("SELECT ID FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE guid='%s';", $image_url )); 
$image_attachment_id = $attachment[0];
$attachment = array(
    'ID' => $image_attachment_id,
    'post_parent' => $post_id
);

$attachement_id = wp_insert_attachment( $attachment );
set_post_thumbnail( $post_id, $attachement_id ); // also tried using $image_attachment_id but same issue
```

I got this blank featured image

[image]

Prior thanks to any help.

Comment: Is the image there but blank, or not actually there at all?

Comment: Yes it creates the file, but actually is blank.

Comment: key question is where in the process does it fail? Can you see the image in another browser? at a greatly different screen or window size? after pulling down the image with ftp, curl, or wget? do all sizes of the image have the same problem (being mindful that with responsive images there's a whole set of images at different sizes)? If you re-upload the image does the problem re-occur?

Comment: ... also, what if you try the 'regenerate' link you showed above?

Comment: Actually the image of size 0 KB, you understand what I mean.

Comment: Yeah, in fact I was rather expecting it to be 0 bytes. If it's the 'original', try uploading again. If it's one (or all) of the resized images, try regenerating. If the generated resized copies are still blank, check the error logs. Then the most likely cause is the generation process hitting a memory limit, which can be conformed by seeing a message in the error log.

Comment: Ah wordpress, I got out of this problem by using wp all import, such a great plugin. Anyways, thanks @LorenRosen :)